# Select order by round table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A like this:

```
WcsID   Single_long, Single_short, Single_tag
1001    100          100           A
1002    100          100           A
1003    100          100           A
1004    100          100           B
1005    100          100           B
1006    100          100           B
1007    100          100           C
1008    100          100           C
```

Is there a good SQL statement to select round on tag? That means I need A-B-C as a round, in above example there are 3 rounds. I need to order by round first, then WcsID in that round, result should be like this:

```
-- round 1
1001        A
1004        B
1007        C
-- round 2
1002        A
1005        B
1008        C
-- round 3
1003        A
1006        B
```

Comment: how 1008 is in Round3 ? it is already in round 2.

Comment: @Amit sorry wrong output, I fixed the output

Comment: @DaleK I have no good way to do it. Currently I wrote a C# function to do this, that is not sql and a big piece of code.

Comment: you can try rank()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(col1 int, col2 varchar(10), col3 varchar(10), col4 varchar(10));
INSERT INTO test(col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES (1001, 100, 100, 'A'),(1002, 100, 100, 'A'),(1003, 100, 100, 'A'),(1004, 100, 100, 'B'),(1005, 100, 100, 'B'),(1006, 100, 100, 'B'),(1007, 100, 100, 'C'),(1008, 100, 100, 'C');

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
        , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col4 ORDER BY Col1 ) rank 
    FROM test
) A
ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: A good answer explains it so OP can learn from it, as well as having a working solution.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer except need col1 after order by rank. I will select this as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT sorted.wcsID, sorted.single_tag,
       sorted.sort AS currentRound
FROM (
    SELECT wcsID, single_tag, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY single_tag ORDER BY wcsID) AS sort
    FROM a
) AS sorted
ORDER BY sorted.sort, sorted.single_tag;
```

The `RANK` function is really good in your situation for such sorting since it allows to both order by that what you are naming "round" and also by the wcsID. Furthermore, you can use it in a subquery in order to select also the "round" you've just created within your result set. To make sure it's also sorted by the single_tag, you can just add it at the end of the main query.